# How much XP is needed for levels 60 through 70?

Tags: diablo-iii

With *Reaper of Souls* coming out soon - and already having gone through a Closed Beta phase -, I was wondering what the XP table from 60 - 70 looks like.

Comment: 460m give or take, that's what I hear

Comment: [Relevant Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/oh-look-its-unreleased-content-again) for this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
60-61: 14,586,000
61-62: 27,000,000
62-63: 29,400,000
63-64: 31,900,000
64-65: 39,100,000
65-66: 46,800,000
66-67: 55,000,000
67-68: 63,700,000
68-69: 72,900,000
69-70: 82,600,000
```

Comment: is that confirmed somehow ?

Comment: I leveled from 60-70 myself last night and wrote down the values as I went.